# check if there is a string followed by another c#

Tags: c#

i need to verify if string is followed by other one in same string variable in C#.
for example:
string phrase= "life is is beautiful";
i need to set TRUE if there is a word followed by other separated by spaces or any. "is" is twice in this string variable. my code reads and find just one character folled by space and says 2. but it just read first character. i appreciate help.

```
  string frase, frase2;
        int secuencia;
       frase="life is is beautiful";            
        secuencia = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < frase.Length; i++)
        {                                 
               if (frase[i]==' ' && frase[i+1]=='i')secuencia++;               
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{secuencia} ");
```

Comment: I think it would help with some examples of input and expected outputs.

Comment: Can you clarify: You want to return true if a word is repeated twice in succession like in your example, but if the word is repeated elsewhere you'd return false? So "word1 word2 word1" would return false, but "word1 word2 word2 word3" would return true?

Comment: Seems like this is your assignment. Please explain us how you approach your problem, which solutions have you already tried? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: its simple task, to read a string and bool true if there is a word followed another one..no matter if there is 1 matches or more.. BUT SEPARATED BY SPACE. word1 word1 word2 word3 word3 ITS TRUE..(2 matches)

Comment: @dymanoid my code explain counting spaces followed by character i, but its not functional for word or word beginning with other letter. but thats what im stack ,,i dont know how to do that..thanks for answer

Comment: @JonasH "life is is beautiful, do do you think is it it real"  this string has 3 matches about question "is" "do" "it". I NEED  bool if there are words followed same words separated by spaces, no matter if there is 1 or 4 matches..

Comment: Split string by space frase.Split(" "). then you will have a list of strings and iterate over it to catch matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot depends on what size of strings you want to deal with and performance needs, but a naive way to approach this would be:

```
var splits = frase.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < splits.Length - 1; i++)
{                                 
     if (splits[i]==splits[i+1]) secuencia++;                
}
```

Comment: it works...just if u illuminate me..what about there is no SPACES between. if there is any word not followed (or yes) in the same row REPEATED.. i mean splits[i] == any other word in same string,,how would u do it? @Paddy

Comment: @AndrésDaza - I think you could probably figure this out using a similar approach.  You now have a list of all the 'words' - if you want to find out if there are more than one of the same word in this string, I'm sure you could think of a way?